# Can an Amulet of Mighty Fists have restricted special abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, magic

If I have an [amulet of mighty fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists) and some claws, can I enchant the amulet with the [keen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/keen) and/or [vorpal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/vorpal) weapon special abilities? If so, do they simply not function for somebody who wears the amulet who doesn't have claws or a similar slashing/piercing natural weapon?

If this works, which I assume it would, can I use the keen/vorpal amulet in conjunction with my unarmed strike via use of [boar style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/boar-style-combat-style) to deal slashing damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keen or vorpal: Yes.

Keen *and* vorpal: No, because AoMFs have a +5 enchant limit.

Yes, they'd only work if the weapon at hand was slashing, its slashiness coming from claws or boar style should be fine.